# ios opengl es 2.0 2D + 3D combination

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to combine 2D and 3D in OpenGL ES "2.0" and even though there are many questions here on openGL es 1.0 and some on 2.0 I am having trouble trying to figure this out. So for 2D I am going off of this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1 and for the 3D I am using the existing cube rotating xcode template...

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the second glDrawArray (somehow its thinking that the original buffer still applies? anyway to unbind this before drawing the 2D texture?) error with the following render function. It works if I disable the lines:
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

What's going on? Thanks in advance.

[code]

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

// glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArrayNum);
// glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayNum);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferNum);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferNum);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gCubeVertexData), gCubeVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f);
// baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(baseModelViewMatrix, _rotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with GLKit
// GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f);
GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(_rotation, 0, 1, 0);
//modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, _rotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;

glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayNum);

// Render the object with GLKit
// [self.effect prepareToDraw];

// glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, 480, 0, 320, -1024, 1048);
self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;

[self.effect prepareToDraw];


glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

[self.player render];
```

[/code]

UPDATE:
Added glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); wrapped around the cube drawing part... which got rid of the bad access error, but neither the cube nor the sprite is being drawn (unless of couse I comment out the code part altogether)...

UPDATE2:
so the problen is obviously that after i call glDrawArray to draw the cube (which works fine)... I call glDrawArray again as follows. But somehow its still trying to render previous array?
    // 1
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;

```
// 2    
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

// 3
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

// 4
long offset = (long)&_quad;        
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, textureVertex)));

// 5    
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me. Works as soon as I do:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

to clear the buffer. I kept looking for glUnbind something... forgot openGL works off of memory references... The 2D texutre is now applying to the cube, but I am sure thats an easy fix :).... That you all for the help >:o

Texture issue fixed :)